# Android: HttpClient, cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity

Tags: android, http, httpclient, httprequest

Trying to send file content to server from Android application like this:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

final InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    gdFileSystemDelegate.openFileInput(openFileInput(FilePath), -1);
reqEntity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

But its throws an exception:
   cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity

What does it mean ? how to fix that ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set protocol param  http.protocol.expect-continue to true in DefaultHttpClient:

```
@Override
protected HttpParams createHttpParams() {
    HttpParams params = super.createHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);
    return params;
}
```